# Asynctask not working on real devices

Tags: android, mysql, android-asynctask, androidhttpclient

Before this post I have not found a post for my issue to be helpful for me.
First, I'm building a very simple android application that should connect to database (MySQL) to load foods data (food name) into ListView with count of food listed.

DB : db_food_resto

Table :

```
#id_row  : int autoincrement primary key.

food_name : varchar 255 not null

food_country : varchar 255 not null //till now i don't need this column maybe in the future this way i added this.
```

I'm using eclipse with Genymontion emulator all things are great with no error compiler no exception thrown and work fine on emulator when I test it on cell phone the list of food not loaded however its loading on tablet!

I'm using asynctask to get the data I don't know why its not working on cell phone and working on tablet.

I have beat my head on this problem for days.

This is my code with some modifications to let it a little bit shorter.

public class HistoryActivity extends Activity
    {
        static ArrayList arr = new ArrayList<>(); // Info is a class contain a food name attribute and one constructor with one argument foodname

```
    ListView historylistfood;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    TextView foodcount;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                             ...
                             ...
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            new Tasklist().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"load_all");

            }
            else {
                new Tasklist().execute("load_all");
            }
     }

    class Tasklist extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            StringBuffer sb = null;
            try
            {
                String link="mydomain.com/file.php?type="+params[0];
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link); 
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent())); 
                sb = new StringBuffer("");
                String line="";

                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    sb.append(line);        
                    //sb is a list of foods gotten from PHP file seperated with |
                    //something like that: food name 1|food name 2|food name 3|ABC|
                    //then i  break the loop
                     break;
                 } 
                 in.close(); 

                getlistfood(sb.toString());

            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace() ;
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(arr.size()>0)
            {
                ArrayAdapter<Info> adapter = new HArrayAdapter(); 
                historylistfood.setAdapter(adapter);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On post exectue", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                foodcount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                foodcount.setText(""+arr.size());
                foodcount.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.movecount));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Intenet issue.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // this is what cell phones showed
            }
        }
    }


    public void getlistfood(String st) {

        arr = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] spl =  st.toString().split("|");
        for(int i=0;i<spl.length;i++)
        {   Info i = new Info(spl[i]);
            arr.add(i);

        }
    }

    public class HArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> 
    {
        public  HArrayAdapter() {
             super(HistoryActivity.this,R.layout.activity_item,arr);
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View itemv = convertView;
            Info poo = arr.get(position);
            if(itemv== null)
            { 
                itemv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_item, parent,false);
            }

            TextView foodname = (TextView)itemv.findViewById(R.id.food);
            foodname.setText(poo.getFoodname()); 
            return itemv; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you declared internet permission in manifest?

Comment: Thank you for your comment; Yes sir i have declared.

Comment: Did you find any errors while running in a device? Please check your logcat for error or warnings.

Comment: no errors in a device blank listview (its like UI cannt modify on cell phone and can modify on tablet !!)
About Log i will check line by line

Comment: 05-11 10:52:42.250: I/ActivityManager(417): Displayed com.android.restofood/.HistoryActivity: +744ms
05-11 10:52:41.502: I/Choreographer(1242): Skipped 115 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: finally i got hard line for android cell phone!!
is String t =  Y.substring(0,2);
i change to   String t = new String(Y.substring(0, 2)); and i added the lenght of  'Y' as a  condition
if( Y.length()>2) // the string should have more than 2 characters
{
String t = new String(Y.substring(0, 2));
}
Now its working fine :)